# Not able to insert into database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert data into database through Codeigniter, but I am not able to proceed. I have a database `mydatabase` with 5 tables `training_assignment_id`,`assignment_name`, `assignment_description`, `recordings_required`, and `is_active`. `training_assignment_id` is auto-increment.

Controller-1 **training.php**

```
<?php 

class Training extends MY_Controller {


 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();

 }

 function index()
 {

   $this->load->helper(array('form'));
   $this->load->view('training_admin');

 }
 /*
 function input()
 {
     $this->load->model('training');
     if($this->input->post('mysubmit')){
        $this->training->training_assignment_insert();
    } 
 }*/
}

?>
```

Controller-2 **add_training.php**

```
<?php 

class Add_training extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('training');
 }

 /*function index($assignment, $description, $check, $radio)
 {
   $assignment=$this->input->post('assignment');
   $description=$this->input->post('assignment2');
   $check=$this->input->post('assignment3');
   $radio=$this->input->post('is_active');

   //query the database


   if($assignment!=NULL || $description!=NULL || $check!=NULL || $radio!=NULL)
   {
     $this->training->training_assignment_insert($assignment, $description, $check, $radio);
     echo 'inserted successfully';
   }
 else {
     echo "Data has not been inserted";      
   }  

 }*/

 function index()
 {

     $this->training->training_assignment_insert(); // this should forward them to the Model

    }
 }

?>
```

Model **training.php**

```
<?php
Class Training extends CI_Model
{
 function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }
 function training_assignment_insert($data ){

$data = array(
        'assignment' => $this->input->post('assignment', TRUE),
        'description' =>$this->input->post('assignment2', TRUE),
        'check' => $this->input->post('assignment3', TRUE),
        'radio' => $this->input->post('is_active', TRUE)
     );
    $this->db->insert('training_assignment', $data);
 }
}
?>
```

View **training_admin.php**

```
    <html>
 <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>resources/training/mystyle.css">
    <title>Assignment</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <h1>Add Assignment</h1>
   <div id="body">
   <?php echo form_open('traning/add_training'); ?>
   <div id="label">

            <input type="text" name="assignment" placeholder="Assignment Name" style="margin-left: 15px;"/>
            <br/>
            <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="assignment2" placeholder="Assignment Description" style="margin-left: 15px;"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <label>Recording Require: </label>
            <select name="assignment3">
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
            </select>
            <br/>
            <label for="active">Enable </label>
            <input type="radio" name="is_active" id="enable" value="1"/>
            <label for="female">Disable </label>
            <input type="radio" name="is_active" id="disable" value="0"/>
            <br/>
        <input class="class1" type="submit" value="Assign"/>
   </div>
     <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
     </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please anyone help me I am new for the CodeIgniter.

Comment: i cant see traning controller having add_training functions

Comment: you need to pass your post values in model function model function don't get directly post values

Comment: Mohit add_training is also a controller. Here form_open('traning/add_training'); traning is the main folder of modules.

Comment: Mohit that is not 2 controller form_open('traning/add_training'); I have given path here. add_training is only controller "traning" is folder name of my module. don't get confuse

Comment: you provides us training.php i just thought its your controller

Comment: try like this form_open('traning/add_training/index');

Comment: I have tried this also but nothing happens

Comment: any kind of error you getting

Comment: That's the main issue I am not getting any kind of error

Comment: Will check it once I will give you remote access

Comment: Mohit I am waiting for you on skype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

controller

```
  <?php 

class Add_training extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('training');
 }

 function index()
 {
 $insert = array(
        'assignment' => $this->input->post('assignment', TRUE),
        'description' =>$this->input->post('assignment2', TRUE),
        'check' => $this->input->post('assignment3', TRUE),
        'radio' => $this->input->post('is_active', TRUE)
     );
     $this->training->training_assignment_insert($insert); // this should forward them to the Model

    }
 }

?>
```

model

```
 <?php
    Class Training extends CI_Model
    {
     function __construct()
            {
                parent::__construct();
            //    $this->load->database();
            }
     function training_assignment_insert($data ){
              $query = $this->db->insert('training_assignment', $data);
             if($query){
                  return true;
               }
           }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass post values to model try 
controller

```
function index()
 {
     $data = array(
        'assignment' => $this->input->post('assignment', TRUE),
        'description' =>$this->input->post('assignment2', TRUE),
        'check' => $this->input->post('assignment3', TRUE),
        'radio' => $this->input->post('is_active', TRUE)
     );
     $this->training->training_assignment_insert($data); // this should forward them to the Model

    }
```

and model :-

```
function training_assignment_insert($data ){

    $this->db->insert('training_assignment', $data);
 }
```

Comment: No Changes Rakesh :-/